# Removed duplicated in sorted array and push them into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, duplicates

I'm trying to store duplicate arrays into a new array but I keep on getting an empty array in the console. Please help.

```
function removedIntegers(arr) {
  let sortedArr = arr.sort();
  let j = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    if (sortedArr[i] != sortedArr[i + 1]) {
      j.push(sortedArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return j;
}
```

Comment: Could you please say what language this is (so we know the scoping rules for variables) and show the program that calls removedIntegers.

Comment: could you share how you are invoking this function and the array you are using, it worked for me when I put your function in a js fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Though your code is working fine,

```js
let years = [2020,2020,2021,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027]
function removedIntegers(arr) {
  let sortedArr = arr.sort();
  let j = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    if (sortedArr[i] != sortedArr[i + 1]) {
      j.push(sortedArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return j;
}

console.log(removedIntegers(years))
```

In ES6, the code is simpler than before for duplicate removal.

```js
let years = [2020,2020,2021,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027]
function sortAndUnique(arr){
return [...new Set(arr.sort())]
}

console.log(sortAndUnique(years))
```